# Streaming data through sockets continuously in java

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I wanted to send/receive continuous stream of data from one endpoint to another(peer2peer) with push and pull 'able asynchronously

So to first solve communication , I started with jax-ws soap binding webservice since it has an endpoint and ws-addressing for push mechanism but it seems to be a lot of overhead (heavy as per the docs and since unfamiliar with ws-*, I haven't implemented it , as I need multiple clients listening to the stream at a later point and the stream is 24/7 I wanted thread manageable sockets).

Then I took jax-rs but it does not include ws-addressing in it.(jax-rs 2.0)
I also looked at websockets but it required an app server but I want a jvm supportable code

So, Now I am trying to use basic sockets but the problem I am having is streaming the data through socket at server and client receiving it continuously.
It is working for the first read but no further. 
Secondly, how can I make it asynchronous?

```
public class sSocket {  
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{  
    int i = 15000;
    ServerSocket ss;
    Socket socket = null;
    ss = new ServerSocket(i);        
    try
    {
        socket = ss.accept();
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);          

           int iii = 0;            
               System.out.println("New connection accepted " +  socket.getInetAddress() + ":" + socket.getPort());   
               BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
               BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

           while(iii<9)
           {
               Thread.sleep(2000);
               output.write("good" + iii + "\n");
               //System.out.print(input.readLine().toString());
               output.flush();
               iii++;
           }
               //socket.close();
       }        

    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
}

public class cSocket {  
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, IOException{
    Socket client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 15000);     
try{
    client.setKeepAlive(true);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    out.writeBytes("Hi Server! I'm " + client.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\n" );     
     BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
     String s;       
     while(true){
     if((s = input.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println("Message from Server: " + s);
    }}
     //client.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

[toString() unavailable - no suspended threads] I see this halting the code in eclipse. 
The problem seems to be essentially rooted in the input.readLine() in client: error is connection reset : which I assume is because readLine() has reached "EOF"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't keep creating new streams. Use the same ones for the life of the socket, at both ends. You're losing data in the buffers.

You don't need to keep calling setKeepalive(). Once is enough.

Comment: I see that I made some errors on the server code, but I don't see any change, the code at client is still halting.I removed the while(true) and keepAlive at server.

Comment: You're reading with a BufferedReader so you should be writing with a BufferedWriter.

Comment: @EJP am creating a program in which i called socket as socket = new socket(ipadd, port) where ip is 10.0.2.2 and port no is 8080. Am getting an error of toString() unavailable - no suspended threads. How to resolve this error?

Comment: @AndroidOptimist The error isn't 'toString() unavailable'. Read the whole stack trace, not just the bit you like. But why are you asking a new question in a comment on an answer to another question?